# Improper integral $\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)$ exists but $\cos(x^2)$ is not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

> Show that the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)$ exists but $\cos(x^2)$ is not Lebesgue integrable.

I'm asked to prove the above statement. I know that the integral is a special one, but I've not yet found a proof of its existence. And as for proving that it is not Lebesgue integrable, I don't have any idea. All tips appreciated.

Comment: Lebesgue integrability requires $\int_0^\infty|\cos(x^2)|\,dx\lt\infty$.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Okay, any ideas how I would go about proving that it tends to infinity? I thought about 'splitting' the integral into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{\sqrt{n\pi /2}}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi /2}} |\cos x^2|$ and then seeing that each term maybe was greater than some divergent series but I do not see it.

Comment: The answer given by user587192 effectively does what you describe. Alternatively, see if you can show that the set on which $|\cos(x^2)|\ge{1\over2}$ has infinite Lebesgue measure.

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220711/prove-that-int-a-infty-sinf-converges) for a generalized case about the existence of the improper integral. By the other side the comment of @Barry conclude the other part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convergence of the improper integral.**

This is a standard result. A change of variable gives the equivalent integral $$\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{u}}\ du.$$

See this post for the value of the improper integral: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity

See also the following questions:
  -  [Definite integral of $\cos (x)/ \sqrt{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1279592/587192)
  -  [A simple proof of the fact that $\int_0^{+\infty} \cos(x)/\sqrt{x} \text{d}x \neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769653/587192)

**Lebesgue integrability.**

Consider the integrals
$$
\int_0^\infty\left\vert\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{u}}\right\vert\ du=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left\vert\frac{\cos(u)}{u}\right\vert\ du+
\int_{\pi/2}^\infty\left\vert\frac{\cos(u)}{u}\right\vert\ du. 
$$
For the second one, note that
$$
\int_{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}^{(k+1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos u|\ du = 2,
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{2}{a_{k+1}}\leq
\int_{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}^{(k+1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\left\vert\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{u}}\right\vert\ du
\leq\frac{2}{a_k}
$$
where $a_k = \sqrt{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$. But
$$
\sum \frac{1}{a_k}=\infty.
$$
So one must have
$$
\int_{\pi/2}^\infty\left\vert\frac{\cos(u)}{u}\right\vert\ du=\infty.
$$
and thus
$$
\int_{0}^\infty\left\vert\frac{\cos(u)}{u}\right\vert\ du=\infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$, as an improper Riemann integral, is ensured by Dirichlet's test, since $\cos u$ has a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$ is decreasing towards zero. Vice-versa, the divergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|\cos u\right|}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$ is ensured by Kronecker's lemma, since $\left|\cos u\right|$ is a non-negative function with mean value $\frac{2}{\pi}$. In particular $\int_{0}^{M}\frac{\left|\cos u\right|}{\sqrt{u}}\,du \sim \int_{0}^{M}\frac{2\,du}{\pi\sqrt{u}}=\frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{M}$ as $M\to +\infty$.